# Should I model eyelids?

Tags: modeling, rigging

sort of a dumb question that I may already know the answer to, but should I model eyelids on a character that's gonna be able to blink?

Comment: There are mainly two approach to move the eyelids: 1. Using surface rigging 2. Using shape key. You may provide more use cases for your question since it is too broad now.

Comment: it depends on the degree of realism you want, you can either model the eyelid on the face and make them visible even with open eyes, or make them different meshes only visible when you close the eyes, much easier solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have 2 main approaches:

- The eyelids are parts of the face mesh. As Hikariztw said you'll animate them with bones or shapekeys. Not easy to do but for a realistic character it's the only solution.

[image]

- The eyelids are part of the head object but they are separate meshes. You'll rig them to bones and make them go up and down, or rotate, or even just appear and disappear (move outside/inside the head mesh). It's not a realistic solution, so it's good for a cartoon character, and it will be much easier to animate.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I was afraid it'd be a p.i.t.a, this will help a lot!